# How to load methods of a controller from another one?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the following controller:

```
class Tests extends CI_Controller {

        public function update_record_test()
        {
              //some methods
        }
}

?>
```

But I need to execute Method1 method from Controller1 controller. How can I do it?

Comment: can you paste the code for controller1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not much information here, or I may be missing something, but what's wrong with

```
class Tests extends CI_Controller {

    public function update_record_test()
    {
          $controller1 = new Controller1();
          $controller1->Method1();
    }
}
```

Comment: i agree with @AleksG depends on a few things such as the scope of method eg is is it private,public,protected. Is it static?

Comment: Possibly the @OP does not really know him-/herself :)

Comment: I think more information is needed like the code in Controller1 :-)

Comment: Sorry, but I have got the following error: Class 'Controller1' not found in Z:\home\localhost\www\application\controllers\tests.php on line 24

Comment: @user1477886 You said you need `Controller1`. Where it it defined?  If it's in a separate file, did you `include` it?

Comment: It's in separate file. How can I include it?

Comment: `include_once(another_file.php)`

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to execute a function of your main class CI_CONTROLLER, try this.

```
 parent::Method1();
```

Check the http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.extends.php for more examples